# Assigning or creating customized permissions for user/groups of Sharepoint via REST API using c# asp.net core

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, .net, microsoft, asp

I am trying to assign customized permissions to users/groups of SharePoint via the REST API. But from Microsft Graph we have only API to assign folder level permissions (read, write, full control). After seeing some links found out a NuGet package called SharePoint itself. So if there is any other way to achieve the above goal please do share it with me. I have shared a screenshot for reference, where test111 is a Domain grou[image]p in SharePoint and test is a customized permission level I created in Sharepoint

Answer (score 0):

Generally, REST API is used for Front-end, for your requirement, it is better to use CSOM code to assign users/groups permissions in your .Net Core solution.

To connect the CSOM code in .Net Core, you need to use modern authentication (**SharePointOnlineCredentials** class is not supported for .Net Core). [An official article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/using-csom-for-dotnet-standard#using-modern-authentication-with-csom-for-net-standard) for your reference.

[Use the CSOM Library in your ASP.NET Core apps](https://ypcode.io/posts/2020/07/use-csom-aspnetcore/)

For granting permission to users/groups
[SharePoint Online: Grant Site Permissions to User using CSOM.](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2020/04/sharepoint-online-powershell-to-grant-site-permissions-to-user.html)